# Различные цвета для групп точек на 3d-графике

Tags: r

Строю 3d-график при помощи библиотеки rgl. Возникла такая проблема: нужно чтобы точки лежащие в определённых зонах получали определённые цвета. Возьмём в качестве примера такой простой график

```
library(rgl)
open3d()
x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x, y)
plot3d(x, y, z, col = "blue")
```

Предположим, хочу, чтобы все точки у которых `x` меньше -1 были окрашены в зелёный, от -1 до 1 в жёлтый, свыше 1 в красный. Пробовал делать что-то типа такого

```
palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red")) 
col.table <- palette(10)
col.index <- cut(x, 10)
plot3d(x, y, z, col = col.index)
```

Но в таком случае `cut` просто разбивает вектор на указанное число интервалов (в данном случае 10). Можно ли как-то самому указать пороги разбиения?

Comment: Возникла идея разделить исходные вектора на несколько в зависимости от условий, и затем несколько раз вызывать функцию `plot3d` с аргументом `add = TRUE`, что все точки были на одном графике, но может быть есть более простой способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл довольно простое решение. Создаём функцию-правило по которому будут присваиваться цвета:

```
givecolor <- function(x)
{
  if(x < -1) "green"
  else if(x <= 1 && x >= -1) "yellow"
  else if(x > 1) "red"
}
```

С помощью функции `sapply` формируем вектор цветов в соответствии с заданным правилом:

```
colors = sapply(x, givecolor)
plot3d(x, y, z, col = colors)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]